# Processing a list of variables (strings) in to relational format in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I am trying to process the following string which is a record in my data frame  in to a relational format as columns and rows

Below String has 3 set of lists so as a result I will have 3 columns with header value of identifier `"lbl_st"`

```
Test_ls = [
        [
         lbl_st = "TestPrdct",
         min = "",
         max = "",
         type = "dscrt123",
         format = [
                   string,
                   11,
                   "",
                   ""
                  ],
         sample_ls = [
                      "GM_TEST",
                      "GL_TEST"
                     ]
        ],
        [
         lbl_st = "TestCTRY",
         min = "",
         max = "",
         format = [
                   string,
                   35,
                   "",
                   ""
                  ],
         type = "dscrt1345",
         sample_ls = [
                      "ES"
                     ]
        ],
        [
         lbl_st = "TestPrtnr",
         min = "",
         max = "",
         format = [
                   string,
                   35,
                   "",
                   ""
                  ],
         type = "dscrt1",
         sample_ls = [
                      "S&G",
                      "Something Test",
                      "Abcd Test",
                      "Bcvd Test"
                     ]
        ]
       ]
```

Below is the output format I am trying to achieve

```
TestPrdct;TestCTRY;TestPrtnr
GM_TEST;ES;S&G
GM_TEST;ES;Something Test
GM_TEST;ES;Abcd Test
GM_TEST;ES;Bcvd Test
GL_TEST;ES;S&G
GL_TEST;ES;Something Test
GL_TEST;ES;Abcd Test
GL_TEST;ES;Bcvd Test
```

I tried using strsplit but I am not sure how to iterate through a list with in a list. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not valid R code. You could make it valid with substitution of the leading and trailing double-quotes by single-quotes and addition of another closing paren. Is that the question you are attempting to ask?

Comment: Your sample code won't load as is. You either need to escape the internal double-quotes, or wrap the string within single-quotes instead. Also missing a close parentheses at the end. (Edit won't let me make the change as it is only 3 characters)

Comment: @42- Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to split the above said string (list of values) in to relational format. I have corrected the code snippet.

Comment: Looks like it came from an external source and should have been processed with a JSON-aware input function. I would suggest taking a couple of steps backwards and redoing the input process.

Comment: @42- I am querying this from oracle DB using JDBC connector in R and trying to convert the values from this list to columns and rows format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[` with `list(` and `]` with `)` and `string` with `"string"`.  Then we can parse and evaluate it to an R list, `L`, and create every combination of columns to get `DF`.  Finally, add column names, convert columns to character and sort.

```
Test2 <- gsub('string', '"string"', gsub("\\]", ")", gsub("\\[", "list(", Test_ls)))
L <- eval(parse(text = Test2))

DF <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(L, function(x) unlist(x$sample_ls)))

names(DF) <- sapply(L, "[[", "lbl_st")
DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.character)
o <- do.call(order, DF[1:2])
DF <- DF[o, ]
```

which gives:

```
> DF
  TestPrdct TestCTRY      TestPrtnr
2   GL_TEST       ES            S&G
4   GL_TEST       ES Something Test
6   GL_TEST       ES      Abcd Test
8   GL_TEST       ES      Bcvd Test
1   GM_TEST       ES            S&G
3   GM_TEST       ES Something Test
5   GM_TEST       ES      Abcd Test
7   GM_TEST       ES      Bcvd Test
```

**Note:** The input `Test_ls` in reproducible form is:

```
Test_ls <-
"[\n        [\n         lbl_st = \"TestPrdct\",\n         min = \"\",\n         max = \"\",\n         type = \"dscrt123\",\n         format = [\n                   string,\n                   11,\n                   \"\",\n                   \"\"\n                  ],\n         sample_ls = [\n                      \"GM_TEST\",\n                      \"GL_TEST\"\n                     ]\n        ],\n        [\n         lbl_st = \"TestCTRY\",\n         min = \"\",\n         max = \"\",\n         format = [\n                   string,\n                   35,\n                   \"\",\n                   \"\"\n                  ],\n         type = \"dscrt1345\",\n         sample_ls = [\n                      \"ES\"\n                     ]\n        ],\n        [\n         lbl_st = \"TestPrtnr\",\n         min = \"\",\n         max = \"\",\n         format = [\n                   string,\n                   35,\n                   \"\",\n                   \"\"\n                  ],\n         type = \"dscrt1\",\n         sample_ls = [\n                      \"S&G\",\n                      \"Something Test\",\n                      \"Abcd Test\",\n                      \"Bcvd Test\"\n                     ]\n        ]\n       ]"
```

> 

Comment: @Grothendieck Thanks a million. This is what I was looking for